# Backup large files in an external disk

Tags: backup

After suffering a few times of external hard disk failure ( it seems that if a disk is a remote hard disk there is a higher chance for it to develop bad sectors), I am now thinking about the backup.

What is the most frictionless solution for backing up large files that are located in an external disk?

Answer (score 1):

Rsync is nice locally, because it'll only copy the parts of the file that have changed. Schedule it to run automatically to sync your data to the drive (but remember to test recovery every now and then).

Answer (score 0):

Addonics manufactures [a range of HDD duplicators](http://www.addonics.com/products/duplicator/hdd_duplicator.asp) that duplicates hard disks very fast without any connected computers. From naked disks, their solutions also support USB-to-USB copy, etc. Do check it out.

We have one in the office, limited application, but it is the most *frictionless* way to duplicate large files (in fact, the whole disk) to another.

Answer (score 0):

Funny - I tend to use my external harddrive ***as*** my backup drive :)

On my network, I have an Ubuntu box that serves as my main data storage point, and I backup the parts of it I'm *really* worried about to an external hard drive, or the other computers on the network - using `rsync` (for the other linux boxes).