# Portable Hard Disk Choice

Tags: hard-drive

I am looking for a reliable portable hard disk solution ( a few hundred GBs). Since I am constantly travelling, and all of my important data is stored on that hard disk, and since I have to connect that hard disk to a desktop all of the time, I have to look for a solution that is reliable. External casing with external hard disk doesn't seem to work out, because they always fail and give me all sorts of scan disk/ check disk error.

One thing I don't like about external casing is that the casing and the hard disk inside it gets burnt pretty easily. My experience is that either the casing spoiled all the time, or the [hard disk inside](https://superuser.com/questions/37189/bad-sectors-relocation-on-windows-xp) [it developed bad sectors rather easily](https://superuser.com/questions/37247/the-device-device-harddisk1-d-has-a-bad-block). [I am also looking into large files backup](https://superuser.com/questions/37244/backup-large-files-in-an-external-disk), but still, nothing beats a reliable portable hard disk.

**Edit: The hard disk should not fail easily-- even if it fails, it should have auto redundancy ( something like raid 1)**

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

If you are having trouble with the reliability of "traditional" hard drives, there are more rugged alternatives.

Have you considered **USB flash drives**? When traveling, space/weight is a big consideration. These things are *fit-in-your-pocket* tiny. You can get 64 GB drives in the $100-$150US range. There are 128 GB drives but they are pricier. I would buy several 64 GB drives.

If performance is a consideration, **solid-state hard drives (SSD)** are the next big thing. You can get external models that are really fast. Without any moving parts, they are very reliable for travel. And they come in much larger capacities. Link: [Say goodbye to your hard drive](http://www.crucial.com/promo/index.aspx?prog=ssd).

Answer (score 2):

The Western Digital Passport series is well received, for example:

- [320G (Newegg)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136227)
- [500G (Newegg)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136301)
- [500G (Amazon)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001F9LY14)

Comment: I've heard good things about them, too

Answer (score 1):

and here's the Big Daddy:

[WD My Passport Essential SE **1 TB** Portable Hard Drive](http://www.wdc.com/cN/products/products.asp?driveid=691)

if you're looking for a more robust solution, then it's getting pricey :)

[Transcend 1.8” eSATA / USB Solid State Drive 128 MB](http://www.transcendusa.com/Press/index.asp?LangNo=0&PrsNo=1222&axn=Detail) ($350)